# golang cgo check if C function exists

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm linking a library via CGO, and not all implementations or versions have a feature which I'd like to utilize if possible — namely the presence of a function `int feature(void)`. Is there a way I can check if this symbol is defined before attempting a call?

Any attempted use of `C.feature()` unsurprisingly results in a build failure on systems with a version of the library that doesn't support the feature.

In case it isn't clear, I want to build against many platforms, which may or may not have the feature. I imagine I'd either need to be able to check if a function exists at runtime (more ideal) or use `go:generate` to do a check and change the code depending on what it finds (less ideal). Either way, I'm not too sure how exactly to proceed.

Comment: If you need something like a shell command to check the lib symbols, on unix systems you could use *strings* and the path to the lib you're linking. With a grep on the symbol name and you could verfy it. And I think is ok for windows too.

Comment: By using something like c preprocessor directive *#if def* looks not possible as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/SSc_ut2hasM).

Comment: If all else fails, you could take this one level deeper, to `dlsym`/`GetProcAddress`. Ironically the procedure differs again per platform, but this time only Windows vs Posix, which should be manageable by build constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries come with a `#define` that describes its version.

For example, in version 1.0:

```c
// simple.h
#define LIB_SIMPLE_VERSION 0x00010000

void hello();
```

In version 1.1:

```c
// simple.h
#define LIB_SIMPLE_VERSION 0x00010001

void hello();
void bye();
```

You have many choices:

- Provide an `IsByeAvailable()` function to check the existence
- Modify the signature of `bye()` in Go such that it returns an `error`, or a `bool` for `ok`
- Panic if the implementation doesn't exist

### Code for Choice 1

```golang
// simple.go

// #include <simple.h>
import "C"

func IsByeAvailable() bool {
    return C.LIB_SIMPLE_VERSION >= 0x00010001
}

func Hello() {
    C.hello()
}

func Bye() {
    C.bye()
}
```

```c
// version_support.c
#include <simple.h>
#if LIB_SIMPLE_VERSION < 0x00010001
void bye() { /* Empty */ }
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that when building your program, but that will leave you with a need to always make two builds and maintain two versions of your program, which is not convenient. In runtime you're very limited because C itself is not reflective and Go runtime features don't (actually can't) give you any benefits.

Still, there are two non-portable (but most probably good enough) hacks you can do. And as the problem is more of a C problem, the hacks are also more of C hacks. One is direct dynamic linker interface, namely `dlopen()`/`dlsym()` and the other one is usage of weak symbols in dynamic linker.

Let's first create some setup to test things out:

```
$ tree
.
├── lib
│   ├── lib1.c
│   ├── lib1.h
│   └── lib2.c
└── some.go
$ cat lib/lib1.h 
int feature(void);
int fun(int a);
$ cat lib/lib1.c 
int feature(void)
{
        return 5;
}

int fun(int a)
{
        return a*a;
}
$ cat lib/lib2.c 
int fun(int a)
{
        return a*a;
}
```

That's a very simple library that declares two functions and has two implementations, one has both, the other just one. Building them is easy:

```
$ gcc -shared -o lib/lib1.so.featured lib/lib1.c 
$ gcc -shared -o lib/lib1.so.featureless lib/lib2.c
```

And a symlink to easily switch between two versions:

```
$ ln -s lib1.so.featured lib/lib1.so
```

So, for the `dlopen()`/`dlsym()` you create a wrapper and use dynamic linker interface to get the `feature()` pointer like this (yes, you can do that without calling `dlsym()` on every call, but let's use the very minimum code):

```
package main;

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Llib -Wl,-rpath lib -l1 -ldl
// #include "lib/lib1.h"
// #include <stddef.h>
// #include <dlfcn.h>
//
// int feature_wrap(void)
// {
//      static void* dlhandle;
//      static int (*featurep)(void);
//
//      if (!dlhandle)
//          dlhandle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
//      if (!dlhandle) // error
//          return 0;
//      featurep = dlsym(dlhandle, "feature");
//      if (featurep)
//          return featurep();
//      else
//          return 3;
//}
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
     r := C.feature_wrap()
     fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Testing:

```
$ go build some.go
$ ln -sf lib1.so.featured lib/lib1.so
$ ./some 
5
$ ln -sf lib1.so.featureless lib/lib1.so
$ ./some
3
```

For the weak symbol approach (that is preferrable IMO as it is simpler) you need to redefine you `feature()` function as weak and also create a wrapper for it that will provide runtime switch between two implementations:

```
package main;

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Llib -Wl,-rpath lib -l1
// #include "lib/lib1.h"
// int feature(void) __attribute__((weak));
// int feature_wrap(void)
// {
//      if (feature)
//         return feature();
//      else
//         return 3;
//}
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
     r := C.feature_wrap()
     fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Testing is the same.

Obviously, once you have proper `if`, you can do whatever you need to substitute missing `feature()` including callbacks to Go code.